# How to get input onto a new line with Assembly Language (Intel 8086)

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm asking a user to input a uppercase and it converts it to lowercase. I need the lowercase to be displayed on a new line. Here is my code:

```
org 100h
include 'emu8086.inc'   
printn "Enter a upper case character"  
mov ah,1
int 21h ;input a character into AL
mov bl,al
mov ah,0eh
mov al,bl
add al,20h
int 10h ;display lower case
```

The output should be like:

```
-> Enter a upper case character
-> A
-> a
```

Current Result:

```
-> Enter a upper case character
-> Aa
```

How do I get the lowercase a to the new line?

Comment: Print a [newline character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) before printing the lowercase letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence for a new line is `0Dh 0Ah`. You can print this sequence with [`int 10h / 0Eh`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm) as if it were characters:

```
org 100h
include 'emu8086.inc'   
printn "Enter a upper case character"  
mov ah,1
int 21h           ;input a character into AL
mov bl,al

mov ah, 0Eh       ;print new line sequence
mov al, 0Dh
int 10h
mov al, 0Ah
int 10h

mov ah,0eh
mov al,bl
add al,20h
int 10h           ;display lower case 

ret
```